# Azure mobile app authentication custom

Tags: android, azure, authentication, azure-mobile-services

We have designed azure mobile app back-end with custom security which accepts username and password from user for azure active directory and then user gets bearer token for further requests.

This works very well. but strangely, we cannot find a way to pass bearer token from android to table controller endpoints.

went custom because we are making changes to existing application and do not want to redirect user to oauth page for authentication.

On the server side we are using azure adal..

It's bit complicated but is it a limitation of mobile app ?

Any help would be great..

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap the bearer token for a ZUMO token.  This is discussed in detail in Chapter 2 of the ZUMO Book: http://aka.ms/zumobook